# How to filter specific names and date on regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to remove some unwanted data from a string with a regex. A specific text and a date (DD/MM format)

What I've tried is:

```
\b(?!REMOVE|THIS|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])))\b\S+
```

from a string 'REMOVE THIS 10/10 KEEP THAT'

unfortunately, it does not work on date. This regex would return '/10 KEEP THAT'. While I want only 'KEEP THAT'

Can anyone help with what i'm missing?

Comment: So it's always DD/MM? and you just want to keep the date and any stuff *after* the date?

Comment: @JoelHager always dd/mm and dont wanna keep the date. I want only the text after the date

Comment: Is there any other date like format within REMOVE THIS OR KEEP THAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: `/.*(\d\d\/\d\d)\b(.*)/`

Basically it creates a capture group *after a date that is after a string of 0 or more characters.

```js
const regex = /.*(\d\d\/\d\d)\b(.*)/;
const string = 'REMOVE THIS 10/10 a5sd6sd56s56  1/1/1/1/3/6/3/63/3/63 KEEP THAT 1235632';

const result = string.replace( regex, `$2`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will not work. Recall that KEEP THAT can contain digits too

Comment: Ah. I must've missed that. I've edited my code. It should work for you now, as long as the `DD/DD` is followed ('D' being digit)

Comment: @JoelHager nice. I will use that. Thanks!